# Spring handle jQuery Sortable

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using a jQuery sortable just like in https://jqueryui.com/sortable/. My code to serialize and send to the server is as follows:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
        update: function (event, ui) {
            var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
            $.ajax({
                //data: data,
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/categoryId/order?order=' + data
            });
        }
    });
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
```

On the Spring side my method signature is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{categoryId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView saveOrder(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("order") List<String> order, @PathVariable("categoryId") String categoryId) throws Exception {
```

Yet, I cannot get spring to process the sent order into the List. I get on the browser a 400 (Bad request) error:

> Required List parameter 'order' is not present

The call from the browser is:

/categoryId?order[]=1&order[]=0&order[]=2&order[]=3&order[]=4&order[]=5

Comment: Are you sure, your request has parameter `order`? My guess is you are entering page without parameter initialy and since default value for `@RequestParam`'s require attribute is true, error is raised.

Comment: I am not trying to solve the issue of missing order parameter. I DO want to process it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `@RequestParam("order")` with `@RequestParam("order[]")`

or

replace `/categoryId?order[]=1&order[]=0&order[]=2&order[]=3&order[]=4&order[]=5` with `/categoryId?order=1&order=0&order=2&order=3&order=4&order=5`

Answer (score 0):

var data=sortable('serialize') it return String, so use @RequestParam("data")  String s;